# How can I run a project that is in the same solution?

Tags: c#, project, solution

I have two projects in one solution. What I want to do is have one project as a main project(Project 1) and every now and then it will launch the other project(Project 2). I want make Project 1 continuously running and every minute,I want Project 2 to launch, run, then close.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
        if (CurrentTime.Minute % 2 == 1 && CurrentTime.Second == 30 && CurrentTime.Millisecond < 5)
        {
            try
            {
                string ThisDir = Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName + "\\Project2\\bin\\Debug\\Project2.exe";
                Process.Start(ThisDir);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```

The problem is that if I want to run it in release this doesn't work.

Another note is that because I don't want this always running, I don't want to set it as a starting project in the solution properties. Is there a better way of starting another project that is in the same solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we've done in the past is `Properties`->`Build Tab`->`Output path`. We usually set it to `..\Output\Debug\` for the Debug config, and `..\Output\Release\` for the release config. This will put both of your projects in the same output directory, and they will be in the appropriate Debug/Release directories.

This way, you can reference the other .exe in the local directory context.

EDIT: Do this for both projects, and your output folder will be
$(SOLUTION_DIR)\Output\Debug\

Then, you simply have to call:

```
Process.Start("Project2.exe");
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't really think of a "pretty" way of doing this off the top of my head. I guess you could use preprocessor directives to determine the path if you want a quick and dirty solution. Something like

```
#if DEBUG
    string ThisDir = Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName + "\\Project2\\bin\\Debug\\Project2.exe";
#else
    string ThisDir = Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName + "\\Project2\\bin\\Release\\Project2.exe";
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you want that. But something I only learnt recently is that you can start multiple projects at the same time.

e.g. press F5, and the startup project starts running.

Now right-click your secondary project, select Debug->Start New Instance, and it will also run side-by-side with your startup project.